# How to distinct sum() when using joins

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, distinct

I have 2 tables.
One holds the data for OK parts and the other for rejects.

I like to receive data in the following format:

```
| YYYY-MM | SUM(ok.qty) | SUM(reject.qty) | reject % |
```

1) Is it possible to use `JOIN` and then some kind of `DISTINCT sum(ok.qty)`?

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m'), 
    SUM(ok.qty), 
    SUM(reject.qty), 
    SUM(reject.qty) / SUM(reject.qty + ok.qty) as reject_percent
FROM ok
JOIN reject ON ok.id = reject.ok_id
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')
```

2) If not how to eliminate duplicate sub-queries?

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m'), 
    SUM(ok.qty), 
    (SELECT qty FROM reject WHERE ok_id = ok.id), 
    (SELECT qty FROM reject WHERE ok_id = ok.id) / 
        ( (SELECT qty FROM reject WHERE ok_id = ok.id) + SUM(ok.qty) ) 
        as reject_percent
FROM ok
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')
```

Right now had to write one query 3 times.

Database design:

`ok.id` can have mutiple rejects.

[image: Database]

Comment: I think this is where analytic functions like SELECT  grouper, SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY grouper ORDER BY id)
2.
FROM    t_aggregator comes into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this..

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m'), 
    SUM(ok.qty), 
    SUM(reject.qty), 
    ((SUM(reject.qty) / SUM(reject.qty + ok.qty))*100)as reject_percent
FROM ok
inner JOIN (Select Ok_Id,Sum(qty) as qty from Reject group by OK_id) as reject ON ok.id = reject.ok_id
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')
```